# SUM values from table 1 with ENUM condition from table 2

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

I have this query

```
$my_taxes = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(FEE) FROM clients WHERE EMAIL = '$EMAIL'"));
```

Also, I have a secondary table called payments with a column (PAID) with 2 ENUM options (pending and ready)

I need to get a variable that sum total fees by a specific email from table clients but only if the PAID column value from the secondary table is selected as pending.

This what I've tried until now

```
$my_taxes = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(FEE) FROM clients WHERE EMAIL = '$EMAIL' UNION ALL SELECT PAID FROM payments WHERE EMAIL = '$EMAIL' AND PAID = 'pending' "));
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

TABLE 1 [payments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOvew.png)
TABLE 2 [clients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJJk6.png)

**OUTPUT** 50 | **EXPECTED** 25

Comment: It will be better if you update create table and some insert data

Comment: what's the question/problem? what results are you getting and what results are you expecting? if failing; checking for errors at all?

Comment: I just updated the question with some details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try query

```
SELECT SUM(FEE) FROM clients
       INNER JOIN payments ON payments.ID = clients.SID AND PAID = 'pending'
       WHERE clients.EMAIL = '$EMAIL'
```

Comment: Thank you! Something doesn't works what I expected. I just updated the question with some details.

Comment: payment.id and clients.id owned one transaction?

Comment: No. I have another columns in table 1 and table 2 called SID (submission id) where their values are equals. I thought the EMAIL columns solve the problem. Is that SID column helps you more?

Comment: Thank you for your patience! I just updated the question, so check UPDATE 2.

Comment: Oh, everything works smoothly now. Thank you again for your patience. You're the best! :)